# There are many ports opened by system on a Windows 8 computer - are the system files modified?

Tags: network, windows, windows-8

There are many ports opened by system on one Windows 8 computer:

```
PORT      STATE SERVICE      VERSION
135/tcp   open  msrpc        Microsoft Windows RPC
139/tcp   open  netbios-ssn  Microsoft Windows netbios-ssn
445/tcp   open  microsoft-ds Microsoft Windows 7 - 10 microsoft-ds (workgroup: WorkGroup)
49152/tcp open  unknown
49153/tcp open  unknown
49154/tcp open  unknown
49155/tcp open  unknown
49156/tcp open  unknown
49157/tcp open  unknown
```

The 4915x `unknown` ports are opened by system programs like `svchost` and `wininit`.

I think these ports should not be opened, since that:

1. This computer has not be set to be visited remotely.
2. I scanned another Windows 8 computer recently, in my memory there are no or very few open ports.

Is this normal? Are the system files modified?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this computer is connected to domain environment domain controller should be 2008 R2 or higher version. Therefore these ports are needs to open in client side. Sometimes computer might be previously connected to domain and changed to work-group.

Read this [Article.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/identity/config-firewall-for-ad-domains-and-trusts)

Comment: Thank you! I checked and it was really used sometimes to remote control another computer. The link is very useful!